# OneToMany relation in datatable

Tags: jpa

I have a **oneToMany** relation between product(id , libelle , dateOperation ) class and maintenance(id ,nameOperation ,date ) class( a product could be maintained one or many time) , so what i want , is displaying in a datatable those product , the problem is that i don't want to display for each row of product the list of its list of maintenance object ; **But i want to get ONE maintenance Object that have the same date value as product.dateOperation**

Comment: please provide your question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customize your query here is an example  :

```
Query q=em.createQuery("select p from Product p, Maintenance m where p=m.product and p.dateOperation=:d and m.date=:d");

   q.setParameter("d",yourdate);
   List <Product> products=q.getResultList();
   if(products==null) return null;
   else
       return products;
```

Comment: and what can I do if I want to display the attributes of this object ?